# StackOverflow with Random Name Generator in C#

Tags: c#, random, generator, stack-overflow

```
using System;


namespace npcnames

{
    class Program
{



    static string RandomVowel()
    {
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        string[] Vowels = new string[5] { "a", "e", "i", "o", "u" };
        int index = rand.Next(Vowels.Length); 
        string Vowel = Vowels[index]; 

        return Vowel;
    }

    static string RandomConsonant()
    {
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        string[] Consonants = new string[21] { "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };
        int index = rand.Next(Consonants.Length); 
        string Consonant = Consonants[index]; 

        return Consonant;
    }

    static string MaleName()
    {
        string malename = RandomConsonant() + RandomVowel() + RandomConsonant() + RandomVowel() + RandomConsonant();
        return MaleName();
    }

    static string FemaleName()
    {
        string femalename = RandomVowel() + RandomConsonant() + RandomVowel() + RandomConsonant() + RandomVowel();
        return FemaleName();
    }

    static void generateFemaleName(int from, int to, int step)
    {
       

        for (int a = from; a <= to; a = a + step)
        {
         
            Console.WriteLine("Female:");
            Console.WriteLine(a + FemaleName());
        }


    }

    static void generateMaleName(int from, int to, int step)
    {
        

        for (int b = from; b <= to; b = b + step)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Male:");
            Console.WriteLine(b + MaleName());
        }


    }






    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        generateFemaleName(1,10,1);
        Console.WriteLine();
        generateMaleName(1,10,1);

    }
}
```

Hi guys I'm new to coding and everything, if anyone can help me how to resolve this issue I would really appreciate it. Problem is that in my code I keep getting stack overflow and I don't know how to prevent it to execute my program normally. The purpose of the program is to generate male and female names of the random selected vowels and consonants in the list of 10 for each.

Comment: Welcome, did you notice something odd while debugging your `MaleName` and `FemaleName` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
static string FemaleName()
{
   string femalename = RandomVowel() + RandomConsonant() + RandomVowel() + RandomConsonant() + RandomVowel();
   return FemaleName(); //  <== bam!
}
```

Change:

```
return FemaleName();
```

to:

```
return femalename;
```

The short story is the method is continually calling itself. It's exactly the same for `MaleName()`.

Also, while we are fixing things, `Random` initialization should be outside the method:

```
private static Random rand = new Random(); 

static string RandomConsonant()
{
   string[] Consonants = new string[21] { "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };
   int index = rand.Next(Consonants.Length); 
   string Consonant = Consonants[index]; 

   return Consonant;
}
```

Comment: And for MaleName() too.

Comment: And do not create a new Random on each call.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! The fix was so simple just me being dumb as usual. Visual Studio completely set me off track telling me that the problem was in the vowel and consonant methods that I did not consider to look on another things.

Comment: A quick reminder @TheGeneral to apply a spell-checker to your work if you can. I understand the fashion for stylistic misspelling, but please don't do it here.

Comment: A quick summary based on a quick scan on the search device, for your assistance: 26 im -> I'm; 0 ill -> I'll; 78 cant -> can't; 18 ect -> etc; 48 wont -> won't; 28 im -> I'm; 28 whats -> what's; 63 id -> I'd; 6 doesnt -> doesn't; 44 lets -> let's.

Comment: @halfer oh trust me, its not stylistic, its purely just badness

Comment: Righto, fair enough. Could you do me a favour, and commit to using a spelling checker? Your browser is likely to have one built in (it may just need switching on in preferences/settings).

Comment: @halfer any suggestions? edit ahh ok

Comment: What browser/OS do you use? I use Firefox/Linux, and it had/has one pre-installed.

Comment: Chrome/edge windows. There is a basic spell checker, however its not good enough to pick up things like its <==. however ill look around and see what I can find

Comment: Yeah, I hear you - "its" is context-dependent. Sadly "cant" and "wont" won't be picked up, as they are words in their own right (cant = jargon, wont = habit). Also "ill" is a word too. But the others I mention should get a noticeable red underline. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: (For whatever reason the comment space is not spell-checked by Firefox - it only seems to apply to large editor windows. Not sure what other browsers do here).

Comment: @halfer yup all good, I have found a couple of candidates, will see how they go

Comment: Cheers, appreciated 

Answer (score 0):

It will be fixed if you change

```
return MaleName();
```

to

```
return malename;
```

and the same for

```
return FemaleName();
```

to

```
return femalename;
```

It is the string that you want to return.